# Need to run multiple feature file in behave using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-behave

My command in python is 
    `feature_file_folder -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o target/allure-results  --no-capture --no-capture-stderr`
This runs all the feature files but if i want to run only 2 feature files out of 10 i am having problems i can run 1 or all feature file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mention feature file names while executing.

```
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter \
                    -o target/allure-results  \
                    --no-capture \
                    --no-capture-stderr \
                    example1.feature example2.feature
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what [tags](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gherkin.html#tags) are used for. Lets say, hypothetically, the two you want to run are related to logging into a system:

login-from-main-page.feature:

```
@login-tests
Feature: Test logging in from the main page
  Scenario: ...
```

login-from-mobile.feature

```
@login-tests
Feature: Test logging in from iOS App
  Scenario: ...
```

Then you would run behave, specifying those tags:

```
feature_file_folder -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter \
                    -o target/allure-results  \
                    --no-capture \
                    --no-capture-stderr \
                    --tags login-tests
```